# Elasticsearch case-insensitive partial match over multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

I'm implementing a search box in Elasticsearch and I have an Elasticsearch index with the following mappings:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "brand": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'd like, quite simply, to do a query such as (in SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE brand ILIKE '%test%' OR name ILIKE '%test%';
```

I've tried a query such as:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*test*",
            "fields": ["brand", "name"]
        }
    }
}
```

and that gives me my desired result, however, I've noticed that [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) recommend not using `query_string` for a search box as it can lead to performance issues.

I then tried a `multi_match` query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

But that yielded no results. Further, when I used an ngram tokenizer, it returned all documents all the time.

I've consulted countless resources on this and even on StackOverflow there are countless unanswered questions regarding this topic. Could somebody explain how this is achieved in the Elasticsearch world, or am I simply using the wrong tool for the job? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided the sample documents, I have created complete example, what you are trying to do is very much possible in Elasticsearch, with simple boolean should wildcard queries as shown below

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "name.keyword": {
                            "value": "*test*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "brand.keyword": {
                            "value": "*test*"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

You can test above query on below sample documents

```
{
    "brand" : "test",
    "name" : "name foo according to use"   
}

{
    "brand" : "barand name is foo",
    "name" : "name foo according to use"   
}

{
    "brand" : "barand name is test",
    "name" : "name tested according to use"   
}

{
    "brand" : "barand name is testing",
    "name" : "test the name"   
}
```

on above 4 sample documents, query returns below documents

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "73885469",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 2.0,
                "_source": {
                    "brand": "barand name is testing",
                    "name": "test the name"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "73885469",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 2.0,
                "_source": {
                    "brand": "barand name is test",
                    "name": "name tested according to use"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "73885469",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "brand": "test",
                    "name": "name foo according to use"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Which is i believe your expected documents

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the "wildcard" query is also susceptible to the performance issues I mentioned in my question as I believe `wildcard` queries use the same mechanism as `query_string`. Do you know how this is possible without the performance hit?

Comment: @psilocybin you didn't mention about the performance issue, also what issue you faced using ngram analyzer(like with sample and expected documents, i showed in my answer), performance depends on various factors and for that we need to have all the required info about your deployment

Comment: @psilocybin i would suggest to upvote and accept this answer, and ask a follow-up question on performance with your Elasticsearch cluster, node, indices, index on which you are searching with some benchmark numbers of my wildcard query

Comment: @psilocybin did you get a chance to look into my comment?